# Move files and directories older than specific time with the same folder structure

Tags: linux, structure, mv

I want to move all files and directories are located on /etc/ that are older than 90 days to /old-etc directory but with the same structure in the source directory.

Thanks

Comment: Don't move but copy them. `/etc/` is essential for Linux in practice. Don't remove files there without knowing what you do.

Comment: Yeah !! It was just an example, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this :

```
find /etc -mtime +90 -type f -exec bash -c 'install -D "$1" "/old-etc/$1" && rm -f "$1"' -- {} \;
```